# Create a CFRunLoopSourceRef using IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource in Swift

Tags: swift, types, callback, iokit, cfrunloop

I am trying to subscribe to changes in power state on macOS. I discovered there is a way using IOKit, though it is a bit convoluted. I need to import it using `#import <IOKit/ps/IOPowerSources.h>` in an ObjC Bridging header. Then I get access to the function IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource, which has the signature:

```
IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource(_ callback: IOPowerSourceCallbackType!, _ context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>!) -> Unmanaged<CFRunLoopSource>!
```

I got some help from the answer in [Callback method to Apple run loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844012/), but still doesn't manage to create a function of type `IOPowerSourceCallbackType` in Swift. What is the missing piece to have this compile?

Comment: Just so you know; I've added a more extensive example to my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `IOPowerSourceCallbackType` is a **C function**.

According to Apple's documentation these functions are available as closures:

> C function pointers are imported into Swift as closures with C function pointer calling convention
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID148

So the easiest way is to use a closure:

```
IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource({ (context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) in
    debugPrint("Power source changed")
}, &context)
```

A second option is to use a top-level function:

```
func powerSourceChanged(arg: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    debugPrint("Power source changed")
}
IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource(powerSourceChanged, &context)
```

For reference the complete implementation of how I'm using this:

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {
    static var context = 0

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        let loop: CFRunLoopSource = IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource({ (context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) in
            debugPrint("Power source changed")
        }, &WindowController.context).takeRetainedValue() as CFRunLoopSource
        CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), loop, CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

To let it interact with the instance the loop was setup from, you have to pass `self` as context, however `self` isn't a pointer.

When you try to pass `self` as pointer by prepending it with `&` (`&self`), you'll get an error that `self` is immutable.

To convert it a to an opaque pointer you can use the `Unmanaged` class:

```
let opaque = Unmanaged.passRetained(self).toOpaque()
```

Which then can be used as an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`:

```
let context = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(opaque)
```

What we can use as the context for `IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource`.

And then in the callback, by using the `Unmanaged` class again, we can resolve this pointer back to its initiating instance:

```
let opaque = Unmanaged<WindowController>.fromOpaque(context!)
let _self = opaque.takeRetainedValue()
```

**Full example:**

```
func PowerSourceChanged(context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    let opaque = Unmanaged<WindowController>.fromOpaque(context!)
    let _self = opaque.takeRetainedValue()
    _self.powerSourceChanged()
}

class WindowController: NSWindowController {
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        let opaque = Unmanaged.passRetained(self).toOpaque()
        let context = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(opaque)
        let loop: CFRunLoopSource = IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource(
            PowerSourceChanged,
            context
        ).takeRetainedValue() as CFRunLoopSource
        CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), loop, CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode)
    }

    func powerSourceChanged() {
        debugLog("Power source changed")
    }
}
```

**Bonus**

[A related article about CFunction pointers](https://web.archive.org/web/20170307203013/http://nshint.io/blog/2015/10/10/working-with-cfunction-pointers-in-swift/)

Comment: Hi, I have tried your solution, but there are some error `A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context` which I cant solve. Can you help me?

Comment: Seems like the `takeRetainedValue()` in the callback is going to cause a crash, because it consumes an unbalanced retain each time the callback is invoked. Should be `takeUnretainedValue()` in the callback and then `takeRetainedValue()` if we were to remove the runloop later, no?