# Is there a battery level did change notification equivalent for kIOPSCurrentCapacityKey on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, iokit, batterylevel

I am building a Swift app that monitors the battery percentage, as well as the charging state, of a Mac laptop's battery.  On iOS, there is a `batteryLevelDidChange` notification that is sent when the device's battery percentage changes, as well as a `batteryStateDidChange` notification that is sent when the device is plugged in, unplugged, and fully charged.

What is the macOS equivalent of those two notifications in Swift, or more specifically, for `kIOPSCurrentCapacityKey` and `kIOPSIsChargingKey`?  I read through the notification documentation and didn't see any notifications for either.  Here is the code I have for fetching the current battery charge level and charging status:

```
import Cocoa
import IOKit.ps

class MainViewController: NSViewController {

enum BatteryError: Error { case error }

func getMacBatteryPercent() {

    do {
        guard let snapshot = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo()?.takeRetainedValue()
            else { throw BatteryError.error }

        guard let sources: NSArray = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList(snapshot)?.takeRetainedValue()
            else { throw BatteryError.error }

        for powerSource in sources {
            guard let info: NSDictionary = IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription(snapshot, ps as CFTypeRef)?.takeUnretainedValue()
                else { throw BatteryError.error }

            if let name = info[kIOPSNameKey] as? String,
                let state = info[kIOPSIsChargingKey] as? Bool,
                let capacity = info[kIOPSCurrentCapacityKey] as? Int,
                let max = info[kIOPSMaxCapacityKey] as? Int {
                print("\(name): \(capacity) of \(max), \(state)")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Unable to get mac battery percent.")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 

    getMacBatteryPercent()
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

(I'm replying to this almost 3-year-old question as it is the third result that comes up on the Google search "swift iokit notification".)

The functions you're looking for are `IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource` and `IOPSCreateLimitedPowerNotification`.

Simplest usage of `IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource`:

```swift
import IOKit

let loop = IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource({ _ in
    // Perform usual battery status fetching
}, nil).takeRetainedValue() as CFRunLoopSource
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), loop, .defaultMode)
```

Note that the second parameter `context` is passed as the only parameter in the callback function, which can be used to pass the instance as a pointer to the closure since C functions do not capture context. (See the link below for actual implementation.)

Here is my code that converts the C-style API into a more Swift-friendly one using the observer pattern: (don't know how much performance benefit it will has for removing run loops)

```swift
import Cocoa
import IOKit

// Swift doesn't support nested protocol(?!)
protocol BatteryInfoObserverProtocol: AnyObject {
    func batteryInfo(didChange info: BatteryInfo)
}

class BatteryInfo {
    typealias ObserverProtocol = BatteryInfoObserverProtocol
    struct Observation {
        weak var observer: ObserverProtocol?
    }
    
    static let shared = BatteryInfo()
    private init() {}
    
    private var notificationSource: CFRunLoopSource?
    var observers = [ObjectIdentifier: Observation]()
    
    private func startNotificationSource() {
        if notificationSource != nil {
            stopNotificationSource()
        }
        notificationSource = IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource({ _ in
            BatteryInfo.shared.observers.forEach { (_, value) in
                value.observer?.batteryInfo(didChange: BatteryInfo.shared)
            }
        }, nil).takeRetainedValue() as CFRunLoopSource
        CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), notificationSource, .defaultMode)
    }
    private func stopNotificationSource() {
        guard let loop = notificationSource else { return }
        CFRunLoopRemoveSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), loop, .defaultMode)
    }
    
    func addObserver(_ observer: ObserverProtocol) {
        if observers.count == 0 {
            startNotificationSource()
        }
        observers[ObjectIdentifier(observer)] = Observation(observer: observer)
    }
    func removeObserver(_ observer: ObserverProtocol) {
        observers.removeValue(forKey: ObjectIdentifier(observer))
        if observers.count == 0 {
            stopNotificationSource()
        }
    }
    
    // Functions for retrieving different properties in the battery description...
}
```

Usage:

```swift
class MyBatteryObserver: BatteryInfo.ObserverProtocol {
    init() {
        BatteryInfo.shared.addObserver(self)
    }
    deinit {
        BatteryInfo.shared.removeObserver(self)
    }
    
    func batteryInfo(didChange info: BatteryInfo) {
        print("Changed")
    }
}
```

Credits to [this post and Koen.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41528433/10845353).

Comment: FYI looks like you need to import `IOKit.ps` instead of `IOKit` otherwise `IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource` is not found

Answer (score 2):

I'd Use this link to get the percentage (looks cleaner)
[Fetch the battery status of my MacBook with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633503/fetch-the-battery-status-of-my-macbook-with-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1)

And to find changes in the state, use a `timer` to re-declare your battery state every 5 seconds and then set it as a new variable `var OldBattery:Int` re-declare it once again and set it as `NewBattery`, then, write this code:

```
if (OldBattery =! NewBattery) {
      print("battery changed!")
      // write the function you want to happen here
}
```

Comment: You don’t want to use a `Timer` since that approach would be impact performance. Use `IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource` instead → https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1523868-iopsnotificationcreaterunloopsou